# Is this list of particles and interactions complete?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams

As a non-academic enthusiast, I've been trying to get a grip on basic particle physics for some time now. There's some stellar sci-comm (particularly on youtube) that gives a general overview, but the trouble is that there seems to be much disagreement about the specifics.

The most complete video I've found is this one by Arvin Ash: https://youtu.be/TDYex6VSd7o

He concludes that when you account for color charge, handedness and antimatter, you come up with **58 distinct particles/fields**, each with their own permanent properties and possible interactions. Most people gloss over one or more of these aspects, treating color charge or handedness like properties that particles can *HAVE* and *CHANGE* while still remaining the "same particle". I'm inclined to think that if a particle's properties change, it has become a different (even if only slightly different) particle.

So then taking this as a complete list, the next question is about the interactions. They're shown on the diagram as lines between the fermions, but this appears to neglect boson-boson interactions, and is unspecific about the actual products and processes.

Perhaps a better way to specify all interactions is with some Feynman diagrams, in which case *this* image claims to be the complete set:

[image: Feynman Diagrams]

So between the **58 particles** and their **9 interactions**, is this an exhaustive account? (Let me disclaim that I know this is in some sense just semantics, but I'm after a coherent mental picture to base further knowledge on, and feel much more comfortable with at least something solid to work off)

Comment: Complete/exhaustive in what sense? In the sense that this summarizes the Standard Model? Also, have you tried confirming yourself that these are all possible particles and interactions? If so, please let us know what you have tried and where you got stuck. If not, let us know what kind of resources you are looking for.

Comment: There are way more interactions in the standard model. Basically, every term in the standard model lagrangian density is represented by a Feynman rule. Try to see [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.6213), it is a resource of Feynman diagrams and sign convention in the SM.

Comment: So if you have an electron with a property called "speed", and that property changes, would you call that a different particle or is it still the same? how do you know? slippery slope... ;)

Comment: @Codename47 I don't have the math background to do the derivation myself which is why I've come here to ask people with more experience than me. I wouldn't really know where to start at this point. I suppose its rather a lofty goal to try and summarize the SM, but when have humans shied away from a lofty goal haha

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux wow this is a great resource. I wonder then if you would contend that the image on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model#/media/File:Standard_Model_%E2%80%93_All_Feynman_diagram_vertices.svg) is incorrect? It was my assumption that the expanded versions in the document you linked were all encapsulated by the more general representations here?

Comment: @rfl Well that's exactly my point, right? We could take it the other way and say there is only ONE type of particle which can have 58 different properties, but that's not a very useful or concise framework. My goal here is to understand the best way to think about this that can lead to a solid understanding, and surely it's somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @KubbaJ the Wikipedia diagrams you show seem complete but is not the best representation.  For instance the triple Higgs vertex would be included by considering what they call "m"  (any particle with mass) to be the Higgs, but its drawn as a Fermionic line in the diagram. The same goes for the Higgs coupling to vector bosons. 

More relevant,  it completely neglects the details of gauge fixing and Faddeev–Popov quantisation. These leading to diagrams with Faddeev–Popov ghosts and Goldstone Bosons.  

The reference that JeanbaptisteRoux quoted on the other hand is fully precise and correct.